# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar todos los caracteres " * " de un arreglo en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy aprendiendo Js, y tengo un problema donde me pasan un array con varias letras desordenadas, pero dentro esas letras vienen los caracteres " * ", lo que tengo que realizar es acomodar el arreglo y quitar los caracteres " * ", por ejemplo:

```
// Ejecutando la función con el siguiente parámetro:
laClaveSecreta( [ "s", "*", "e", "n", "u", "l", " ", "s", "*", "e", " ", "a", "í", "*", "d", " ", "l", "*", "E", "*"] );  

// El resultado que nos devuelve la función es el siguiente: 
"El día es lunes";  
Otro ejemplo:

// Ejecutando la función con el siguiente parámetro:
laClaveSecreta( ["a", "*", "d", "a", "r", "f", "*", "i", "c", "*", "s", "e", "d", " ", "e", "*", "v", "a", "l", "C"] );  

// El resultado que nos devuelve la función es el siguiente: 
"Clave descifrada";
```

No encuentro la forma de quitar los caracteres "*", ¿Alguna idea?
llevo esto, pero no me corre el código, ya intente con splice(), indexOf(), pero la verdad es que no se como resolverlo.

```
function laClaveSecreta(array){
let ordenado = array.reverse();
let count;
for(let i=0; i<ordenado.length; i++){
    let caracter = ordenado;
    if(caracter != '*'){
     count = ordenado.push(caracter);
    }
}


return ordenado;
```

}

Comment: Pero, ¿qué problema tiene el carácter "*"? Hasta donde yo veo, no se imprimiría, ¿no?. Sino, tienes un condicional if que si hay algo que NO sea * lo ordene, bastaría quizá con poner un else y declarar que si es un * lo borre, ¿o no es lo que buscas?

Comment: Exactamente es lo que busco, pero me surgió una duda, ¿En verdad mi código esta bien? ¿Es decir debería de borrar el "*"?

Comment: Abajo tienes una respuesta perfecta, una solución super optimizada por @Sr187, te libera de casi toda carga innecesaria de código. Igualmente, como consejo de novato a novato (el que me dieron a mi), haz una copia de seguridad del código, borra lo que quieres y prueba. Si no da el resultado que quieres, restauralo, y san se acabó XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la función [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) Que básicamente filtra un array de acuerdo a un callback (o función) pasada.

```js
const clave = [ "s", "*", "e", "n", "u", "l", " ", "s", "*", "e", " ", "a", "í", "*", "d", " ", "l", "*", "E", "*"];

const clave_filtrada = clave.filter(chr => chr !== '*').reverse();
//Ademas aplicando el reverse ya te sale

console.log(clave_filtrada);

//Si quieres unir todo puedes usar el join
console.log(clave_filtrada.join(''));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, una ultima duda, ¿Cómo podría hacer para retornar el array ya "acomodado" es con un return clave_filtrada; ??

Comment: Ya pude @Sr1871, solo tuve que declarar otra variable y asignarle el join para poder retornarlo, me fue de mucha ayuda, Gracias!