# Eliminar caracteres y reacomodarlos en JavaScripts

Tags: javascript, array, parametros

Estoy aprendiendo JavaScript y tengo que resolver el siguiente problema:

Tengo un array con una clave al revés y con caracteres " * ". Tengo que eliminar esos caracteres y reacomodar los array de atrás hacia adelante. Por ejemplo:

// Ejecutando la función con el siguiente parámetro:
laClaveSecreta( [ "s", "*", "e", "n", "u", "l", " ", "s", "*", "e", " ", "a", "í", "*", "d", " ", "l", "*", "E", "*"] );

// El resultado que nos devuelve la función es el siguiente:
"El día es lunes";

He estado desarrollando el código miles de veces y ya no sé que hacer, el ultimo que hice fue este:

```
function laClaveSecreta(conjuntoDeCaracteres){
let resultado = [ ];
for (let i = 0; i < conjuntoDeCaracteres.length; i++) {
  let caracteres = conjuntoDeCaracteres[i];
  if (caracteres != "*") {
    resultado.push(caracteres)
  }
}
return resultado.reverse();
}
```

Vi que se puede utilizar un filtro pero tampoco lo logré y la verdad es que preferiría hacerlo con for (ya que es lo que tengo que poner en práctica). No sé si alguien me pudiera ayudar a descubrir qué esta mal que yo ya estoy atascada:(
Gracias a todos!!!

Comment: Para el filtro que dices, mira esta pregunta, que es exactamente el mismo ejercicio que el tuyo, y se resolvió ayer: [PREGUNTA](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/434953/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-eliminar-todos-los-caracteres-de-un-arreglo-en-javascript)

Comment: Justamente es lo que comenta. Que ha visto que se puede hacer con un filtro pero además de no lograrlo, prefiere hacerlo con for porque es cómo se lo piden. Probablemente su compañero de clase haya hecho la misma pregunta ayer, ya que hasta el nombre de la función es la misma. 
Si bien es cierto que en el mundo real los bucles no son lo más óptimo, para las prácticas es lo primero que te piden aprender.

Comment: Lo se, pero cito textualmente: "Vi que se puede utilizar un filtro pero tampoco lo logré", ya que vi que tu ya le habías resuelto la duda con el bucle, todo conocimiento para aportar es poco. No puse un comentario ya que no puedo, sino, me hubiera ahorrado la respuesta XD

Comment: Bien hecho. Igualmente, y lo digo por cómo son de estrictos los moderadores aquí, las respuestas deben ser únicamente ajustadas al núcleo de la pregunta, si quieren otras respuestas derivadas las deben buscar por sí mismos o preguntarlas explícitamente. Que siempre dan votos negativos a respuestas que no dan el 100% de la solución.

Comment: Bueno, me seguiría acogiendo a que la pobre lo intentó y no pudo, por tanto asumo que también buscaba esa forma de hacerlo, nunca viene mal. Pero gracias por el consejo.

Comment: Gracias por la liga, AQMR, esa fue de las primeras opciones que intenté pero no sé por qué no lo logré. Te agradezco de todas formas:)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo puedo eliminar todos los caracteres " \* " de un arreglo en JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/434953/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-eliminar-todos-los-caracteres-de-un-arreglo-en-javascript)

Comment: Si la pregunta es la misma entonces se marca como duplicado. Por otro lado esto no es una respuesta, sino un comentario

Comment: Ya, por eso reitero en lo mismo de un comentario mío anterior: ' No puse un comentario ya que no puedo, sino, me hubiera ahorrado la respuesta'

Comment: @AQMR ya lo marque como duplicado, los mods veran si migrar tu respuesta como comentario

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/260047)

Comment: Sí pero no, intente hacerlo así pero por alguna razón no lo logré. Muchas gracias de todas formas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado que te piden usar for, ¿por qué no empezar desde el final hacia el principio y ya te olvidas de hacer el reverse?. Si te fijas, el length del for tiene un  -1 porque el length devuelve el total, pero los array empiezan en cero. Además, de esta manera tampoco tienes que convertir el resultado final que es otro array en un string. En el for puedes hacerlo todo de una.

```js
var a =  [ "s", "", "e", "n", "u", "l", " ", "s", "", "e", " ", "a", "í", "", "d", " ", "l", "", "E", "*"];

function laClaveSecreta(conjuntoDeCaracteres){

let frase = '';
for (let i = conjuntoDeCaracteres.length-1; i > -1; i--) {
let caracter = conjuntoDeCaracteres[i];
  console.log("El valor de i es "+i+" -- y el caracter de esa posición en conjuntoDeCaracteres es: "+ caracter);
  if (caracter != "*") {
    frase += caracter;
  }
}
return frase;
}

alert(laClaveSecreta(a));
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!! Solo tuve que eliminar el console.log y el alert porque la plataforma no los aceptaba pero quedó perfecto. Te agradezco de nuevo:)

Comment: El console log está para que sepas qué ocurre en el for, no es necesario.